# how to write a usb storage device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I used the usb driver template usb `skeleton.c` in the kernel and changed `VENDOR_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID` to be able to detect my usb storage device. Then compile this module and install it. Unfortunately, although the probe function works correctly, there is no my device when I execute `fdisk -l`

Before installing the module, I have uninstalled the two modules usb_storage and usa, and renamed usb_storage.ko to ensure that it will not install itself

I want to know how to make the usb storage device be able to display and access normally

Comment: USB mass storage protocol is not about IDs, it also needs protocol to be implemented.

Comment: @0andriy Can you tell me in more detail, I'm just a novice

Comment: Read the code of the existing driver (_drivers/usb/storage_).